# how to implement cache mechanism in kotlin multiplatform using ktor

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I am using ktor library for network calls in one my kotlin multi platform project. Here we are sharing the business logic between iOS and Android. Is there a way to implement cache mechanism in ktor ? I was following below article, but can we add custom time value from our side for expiration or can we do some customization?

Comment: You can use the `HttpCache` plugin (https://ktor.io/docs/client-caching.html). What article did you follow? What do you mean by custom time value from our side for expiration?